# Geospatial, temporal and keyword search using CKAN API on data.gov using ckanclient

Tags: api, data.gov, ckan

Thanks to [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/catalog-data-gov-using-ckan-api-with-python-requests-package)  , I can successfully use the python `ckanclient` package to search `data.gov` for "sea_water_temperature":

```
import ckanclient
q = 'tags:sea_water_temperature'
ckan = ckanclient.CkanClient('http://catalog.data.gov/api/3')
d = ckan.action('package_search', q=q, rows=10)
```

What I really want to do is to query for "sea_water_temperature" in a specific geospatial bounding box and temporal extent, and additionally find only datasets that have a specific data service endpoint.

Adrià Mercader provided these examples on the ckan-discuss mailing list:

```
# WMS + keyword
{"q": "salmon",
 "fq": "res_format:WMS"}

# WMS + temporal
{"q": "metadata_modified:[2013-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]",
 "fq": "res_format:WMS"}

# WMS + spatial
{"extras":{"ext_bbox":"-121,45,-120,46"},
 "fq": "res_format:WMS"}
```

How can I  convert these examples into something `ckanclient` can understand?

Comment: What if you query all the database and then filter what you want from the results? It isn't the best solution, but it is one.

Comment: I could do this, but it negates the whole point of querying.  I know that CKAN can do a filtered search like this, but I'm stuck on the syntax with ckanclient, I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ckan.action` will pass all the keywords parameters onto whatever API call you are using, so you can pass any parameter supported by [`package_search`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api.html#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search) to it (I'll use PDF instead of WMS to get some results):

```
import ckanclient
q = 'tags:sea_water_temperature'
ckan = ckanclient.CkanClient('http://catalog.data.gov/api/3')
d = ckan.action('package_search', q=q, rows=10, fq='res_format:PDF')
```

You can change slightly your code to pass a whole dict of parameters, which makes easier to see what is going on:

```
import ckanclient                                                                                                       
search_params = {                                                                                      
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature"',       
    'fq': 'res_format:PDF',                         
    'rows': 10,                                                                                        
}                                                                                                      

ckan = ckanclient.CkanClient('http://catalog.data.gov/api/3')                                          
d = ckan.action('package_search', **search_params)
```

Use these parameters for the other query types that you needed:

```
# sea_water_temperature + PDF + modified since + bounding box
search_params = {                                                                                      
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature" AND metadata_modified:[2012-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]',       
    'fq': 'res_format:PDF',                                                                            
    'extras': {"ext_bbox":"-121,45,-120,46"},                                                          
    'rows': 10                                                                                        
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome.  I know I'm not to supposed to thank people in comments, but I can't help it:  I never would have figured this out, and now I'm off and running!