# What is a good Python CKAN Tutorial?

Tags: ckan, programming

Where can I find some resources to help me learn how to write Python to CKAN (in this instance `data.gov.uk`) repositories?

I've had some signs of life from bits of code that I've found, but would certainly benefit from some good tutorials.

Comment: I believe this is very similar to this question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/catalog-data-gov-using-ckan-api-with-python-requests-package

Comment: Certainly that's a very useful question, and will likely help me to get past my current roadblock. My question however is if anyone knows of any good tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi ? It is the official and current python client for CKAN.